# How to initialize a C++ object member that is an 2D array of integers

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, initializer-list

I have a class (foo) that has a member (c) that I want to be a two-dimensional array of integers.  For some reason I can't get the initializer list to work properly on the array.

```
49:  class foo{
50:  public: 
51:    int a;
52:    int b;
53:    int** c;
54:    foo(int a_arg, int b_arg, int** c_arg) : a(a_arg),b(b_arg), c(c_arg)
55:    {}
56:  };//end of class
57:  
58:  int main() {
59:    foo bar{5,7, {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}  };
60:  }
```

I have found a lot of member initializer list examples online, but none that specifically deal with a class member that happens to be a C style array (all examples I found seemed to use std::vector or similar).  But please note that this code is going to run in an embedded environment which doesn't support the use of any of the C++ standard template library classes (so no vectors or similar).

If I write this code with just a_arg and b_arg it works fine.  But when I add in c_arg I get the following error message from the compiler.

> src/main.cpp:54:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: cannot
> convert initializer list argument to 'int ** '   foo(int a_arg, int
> b_arg, int** c_arg) : a(a_arg),b(b_arg), c(c_arg)

It looks like the type of **{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}** is not int**.  But if it's not that then what is it?  I have tried adding various type modifiers onto the definitions of c and c_arg but none of them seem to work.

If the third argument is a variable of type int** then it does compile.  But I don't get the initil values like I want.

```
class foo{
  public: 
  int a;
  int b;
  int** c;
  foo(int a_arg, int b_arg, int** c_arg) : a(a_arg),b(b_arg), c(c_arg)
  {}
};//end of class

int main() {
  int** xxx = (int**)malloc(9*sizeof(int));
  foo bar{5,7, xxx  };
}
```

Comment: `{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}` is a braced initializer list. You can use it to initialize an array of arrays, but a pointer to a pointer is not an array of arrays. Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: Don't use pointers, use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: And as a general tip, whenever you need to use a C-style cast when programming in C++ (like you do for the result of `malloc`) then you should take it as a sign that you're probably doing something wrong. The "wrong" in your case is the use of `malloc`. ***If*** you really need to use your own dynamic allocation, use `new[]`. But as I mentioned before, better use `std::vector`.

Comment: Take a step back,"why" do you a C-style array?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The particular embedded environment I am writing this code for does not support use of any of the Standard Template Library classes.  I can't use std::vector because the development environment and compiler I am using doesn't support it.

Comment: @LouisGo I am using C style arrays because this code is for a microcontroller with limited RAM and code space so the development environment / compiler doesn't support any of the std:xxx classes, so I can't use std:vector.

Comment: If you're on such a limited system then perhaps the standard containers are disable because they do dynamic allocations. And that perhaps means you should avoid it as well? If the contents of the arrays are known at compile-time then use actual arrays and initialization of those at definition (as shown in the posted answer by Sync)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  In my context the objects are going to be used as data sources for other code.  It's actually better if I don't even have to make a copy in RAM. 
 The best-case scenario would be finding a way to say to the compiler/linker, "Please format this initializer data into an object and store it in flash memory so I can read it later".  It would be really surprising to me if there wasn't a clean syntax for this in C++ since it exists in a lot of other languages.

Comment: Initialized global variables, or initialized local `static` variables, usually are put into memory that could be located in FLASH. You have to check the linker map file to check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the compiler error, `{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}` is an 'initializer list' and not an array. Also `int** c` is not a two-dimensional array of integers but an pointer to an array of integer pointers. To get what you want you could do something like this in your main function:

```cpp
    int main() {
    
      int  data[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
      int* arr2d[] = { &data[0], &data[3], &data[6] };
    
      foo bar{5,7, arr2d };
    
      std::cout << arr2d[1][1]; // will print 5
    
    }
```

Also note that `int** xxx = (int**)malloc(9*sizeof(int));` is not correct either. You are creating a pointer somewhere in the memory with space for 9 ints, but you are then casting that to an array of 9 int pointers.

Alternatively, if you know that the bound on the second dimension of your array will always be 3 then you could do this:

```cpp
class foo{
public: 
  int a;
  int b;
  int (*c)[3];
  foo(int a_arg, int b_arg, int (*c_arg)[3]) : a(a_arg),b(b_arg), c(c_arg)
  {}
};

int main() {

  int arr2d[][] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} };
  foo bar{ 5, 7, arr2d };

  std::cout << data[1][1];

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the bounds on the array.  The example I gave in my question is sort of a minimal case.  In reality there will be many instances of foo with different size arrays containing potentially thousands of elements.  I was hoping for a way to cleanly initialize an object with a C style array member that didn't rely on generating extra variables.

Comment: So what is the type of "{ {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} }"?

Comment: If you don't know the bounds then there is no C style way of doing it. You could create a class that wraps a 1d array and lets you index it using two variables by overloading the [] operator. Or if you know a list of possible bounds then you could use templates.

Comment: { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} } doesn't have a type. Its an initializer list.

Comment: If you really want to stick to C style I think the best way is to treat it as a 1D array and index it as if it was a NxM 2D array like so: data[ i*N + j ], where i<N and j<M, which would be equivalent to data[i][j].

Comment: I agree with that approach.  Using a 1D array is viable.  I am still trying to figure out if there is a version of the initializer syntax for arrays that doesn't involve creating a second variable.

Comment: Since I can't find any version of the initializer syntax that works without making a separate array somewhere, I will accept this answer.

Comment: There is no such syntax in C++